# Can thread join twice in java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am new to java.
When I review the codebase of my company, I see it do the thread join twice.
Something like this:

```
if (timeout) {
    try {
        this.join();
        this.join();
    } catch(exception e) {}
 }
```

As I learned c/c++, thread will become unjoinable after joined.
Does anyone know what's the purpose of this ?

Thanks for help!!

I tried ask somebody in my team, but they do not know for sure.

Comment: There is no point to joining the same thread twice. `join()`ing a thread that is no longer running does nothing and returns immediately. Also, that code is invalid (`exception` isn't a type).

Comment: For sure the empty catch block is a bad programming pattern and will hide if the second call to join fails.

Comment: What do you _expect_ `join` to do?

Comment: @dan1st, OP is coming from C++ background. C++ requires that every `std::thread` instance must either be `join`ed exactly one time or it must be `detach`ed exactly one time.

Comment: @web_zai, The best way to think about Java `join` is: It does _nothing._ It does absolutely nothing at all until the thread is finished, and then it returns. If the thread was already finished, then join does absolutely nothing at all.